# Parameters of the L2 insertion burn to be done tomorrow

Tags: orbital-maneuver, james-webb-telescope, lagrangian-points

What parameters control the impulse to be applied in the L2 insertion burn? What parameters control when/where it is to be performed?  What velocity is the impulse applied to achieve?  Is the vehicle to go to zero velocity?

The goal would be to minimize this burn to save fuel for future use. The vehicle is only going 450 mph and is still slowing down.   I can't compute a rate of slowdown as there is no plot of the velocity data that I can see.

Anyone have any further info on L2 insertion burn?

Comment: 450 mph is in the rotating frame; of course *it is also going* ~30 km/s around the Sun

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you are looking for here.

Comment: 450 mph is the velocity reported by nasa on "where is webb site".  I was looking to find that an impulse of what value is to be applied when the vecichle is at what position or what velocty and is to change vehicle velocity to what final velocity.  All I can find is a bunch of cartoon phrases and no specifics.

Comment: To partially answer my own question, the "where is webb" site now (12:24 cst) gives 384 miles "to l2 orbit".  This is a completely meaningless piece of info as L2 is not a set spot.  I assume L2 Insertion burn will be done when "distance" gets to 0. ??????

Comment: To rephrase my question, someone is going to fire the thruster manually, right?  When will they do that; upon what trajectory parameters?  And for how long do they do that?  And what parameter values will they terminate the burn based upon?

Comment: some info today: "Around 2 p.m. ET today, JWST will enter the L2 halo orbit, with a 4m 58s MCC-2 thruster burn using 2.3 kg fuel, dV = 1.5 m/s."